# It would (will?) pay you to read about ionisation energies if you really want to understand this

Tags: conditional-constructions

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/bonding/ionic.html#top):

> It **would** pay you to read about ionisation energies if you really **want** to understand this.

Shouldn't it be **will**, this being the so-called First Conditional?

Answer (score 1):

> it would pay you to

is idiomatic here. The meaning is like:

> It would **be worthwhile** to read about ionization energies if you really want to understand this.

The *pay* comes into this since you could profit from the added knowledge, say in your occupation.